# How do I get rid of moss on buildings?

Tags: paradise-island-2

What does green moss on a building mean & how can I get rid of it? I built the  electricity plant and now it has green moss on it. What do I do?

Comment: @Zodack This is a mobile game, I suspect they didn't intend to use that tag.